# Possibilities for customising the standard wordpress gallery?

Tags: gallery, seo

I am a photographer with a Wordpress site so as you might imaging I need to show off my work in it's best light. I love the wordpress gallery because it creates great SEO due to the comments underneath the pictures but there's a problem with the thumbnails.

Firstly I am using the newer version of Wordpress which I am led to believe has less gallery options. I have lots of pictures in both portrait and landscape but the thumbnail is an exact square.

The problem is that in the portrait images, the tops and bottoms are cut off (usually peoples heads) and in the landscapes the sides are cut off.

Is there anything I can do to improve the gallery and show my images bigger without any cropping (e.g. more dynamic)?

Edit: Just to tell you what I've already tried. I have unchecked the fit to exact dimensions checkbox and ran a tool to regenerate the thumbnails but the pictures came back all over the place and they were slightly distorted. They didn't nicely fit together a bit like flickr for example.

Comment: _"Firstly I am using the newer version of Wordpress which I am led to believe has less gallery options."_ ... why that? And what is "newer version of WordPress"? WP has 3-4 new versions every year and is meant to be kept up to date for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Gallery shortcode output is handled by [`gallery_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/gallery_shortcode/) function.

If you look at the source code I linked you can udersand there are different way to customize the output:

### Using filters

You can completely override gallery output using [**`'post_gallery'`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_gallery/) filter.

### Customize size via atts

One of the argument you can pass to function using shortcode is `'size'`, it can be used to make shortcode use a specific image site, one of the default or one custom registered via [`add_image_size`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

E.g.

```
[gallery size="full"]
```

Will make gallery use non resized image.

### Customize using CSS

You can disable the addition of default gallery style by returning false to [`"use_default_gallery_style"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/use_default_gallery_style/) filter hook.

You can also change / edit it using [`"gallery_style"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gallery_style/) filter hook.

Consider you can use the `.gallery-item`, `.gallery-icon.portrait` and `.gallery-icon.landscape` classes in your CSS.

### Using plugins

In the official WordPress plugin repository there are [1385](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=gallery) gallery-related plugins, and if you look in GitHub and in different markteplaces there are hundreds of other.